# How to retransform scikit's LabelEncoder labels?

Tags: python

Quite new to Python here, and I am sure I am missing something in my work but I do not know what to look for anymore...

I did my research and read many examples online on the LabelEncoder function, especially from:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html
and http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#label-encoding and http://biggyani.blogspot.com/2014/08/using-onehot-with-categorical.html.

However, I couldn't find the answer to my question (tried many things on my code too but always running into errors).

Here is a link to the post that describes exactly the problem that I am having: 
http://blog.kaukotyo.fi/blog/python/how-to-retransform-scikits-labelencoder-labels.html

When I try to use the .inverse_transform() on the predicted outcome Y, I got the same error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

But it doesnt make sense to me why I would need to use either .any() or .all().

So my question is, after I predict on the transformed data, how do i retransform (or inverse transform) my outcome to get back to the original label?

below is my code:

```
encoded_vals = encoder.fit_transform(df)

imp = Imputer(missing_values="NaN", strategy='mean', axis=0)   
### i am trying to get rid of all the missing values here so that i can fit into the classifier model later

X = pd.DataFrame(imp.fit_transform(encoded_vals), column=df.columns)
Y_in = X.ix[,pred_col]
clf = RandomForestRegressor(max_leaf_nodes=maxLeafNodes, min_samples_leaf=minSamplesPerLeave)
clf = clf.fit(X, Y_in)
Y = clf.predict(X)
Y = list(encoder.inverse_transform(Y))
```